# Beanstalkd on ec2 with 11300 port open, getting connection refused

Tags: amazon-ec2

Just installed beanstalkd on ec2 - t1.micro and opened 11300 through security groups.
I can do telnet localhost 11300. But telnet from remote gives connection refused 11300.
I know am missing something very basic , but what is it?

Comment: do you have a seperate iptables configuration running?

Comment: Not sure. It is ubuntu 12.04.
netstat --numeric-ports -l | grep 11300
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11300         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 

telnet X.X.X.X 11300
Trying X.X.X.X
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: I had a silly mistake in the beanstalk config. host should be 0.0.0.0 I had it 127.0.0.1 and in security group as 0.0.0.0. Silly - but figured out quickly.

Comment: hey Sid4it I tried to configure /etc/initi.d/beanstalkd and make it listen to local ip address but it still would listen to 127.0.0.1   but when i try beanstalkd -l xx.xx.xx.xx  it then works any thoughts why would it not be from that upstart script?

Comment: @AftabNaveed If you're doing this on Ubuntu you need to edit /etc/default/beanstalkd and make sure BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_ADDR is set to what you want